# Put character in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, string, compare, simpledateformat

I want to validate the code of Date.

Input come from Textbox where user enters it.
and in code it will get calender's date instance and match it.

I want to put character in that SimpleDateFormat.

Code :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'ch' MMM, yyyy");
System.out.println("Date is :: " + formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));


String input = "20th Mar, 2014";

if(input.equals(formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))){
    System.out.println("Matched");
}else{
    System.out.println("Not Matched");
}
```

I want to put `th, rd, st` on place of ch in SDF.
means it will take input from user so it can be any date so I want some mechanism so only three will be placed at there.

Anyone knows that how can I do this ?
Help..

**UPDATE**

```
        SimpleDateFormat formatterth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'th' MMM, yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat formatterrd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'rd' MMM, yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat formatternd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'nd' MMM, yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat formatterst = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'st' MMM, yyyy");

    String input = "20th Mar, 2014";
    String input1 = "23rd Mar, 2014";

    try {
         if(input.equals(formatterth.parse(input1)) || input.equals(formatterrd.parse(input1)) || input.equals(formatternd.parse(input1)) || input.equals(formatterst.parse(input1))){
              System.out.println("Matched");
          }else{
              System.out.println("Not Matched");
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't, basically. You need three separate `SimpleDateFormat` objects:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd'st' MMM, yyyy")
new SimpleDateFormat("dd'nd' MMM, yyyy")
new SimpleDateFormat("dd'th' MMM, yyyy")
```

... then try parsing with each of them. Note that even this only works with ordinals in English... and it will parse "20st Mar, 2014" which possibly it shouldn't.

Ordinals in date formats are fundamentally a pain, and I haven't personally seen any API which deals with them nicely - partly because they're a pain in localization in general.

Comment: Means there is no way to do so in a single SDF ?? Shall I have to compare all 3 in if condition ?? Am i right ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying - I would suggest you have a helper method to try to parse using a collection of date formats.

Comment: Sir will you check UPDATE in question, I have tried this but not working, giving me an error that `Unparsable`, I have seen that using this we can parse string to date.

Comment: @user3145373ツ: `parse` throws an exception if it can't be parsed, and it's clearly not going to be parsable by *all* formats. This is why I suggested a helper method: it will loop until one parser *doesn't* throw an exception. (So repeatedly catch the `ParseException` and move to the next formatter.)

Comment: helper method means ?? Will you give me one small idea about it, I am new to it so i am facing the problem.

Comment: @user3145373ツ: A separate method, which takes a collection of `DateFormat` items and tries each one in turn, returning the `Date` from the first successful parse.

Comment: Ok now get it. I have got similar solution in below answer. He have posted the code also, can you take a look on it.

Comment: @user3145373ツ: The code that's been posted is doing *formatting*, and you're interested in *parsing*, right? So no, that's not what I had in mind. But I'm not just going to give you the code - you *really* should be able to work it out from the hints so far.

Comment: OK thank you sir for the hint, I ll try on it and then ll post you answer. Thank a lot sir..

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that with one Simple date format but you have to get Day from date check what kind of format you want to use.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

SimpleDateFormat formatter;
if(dayOfMonth==1||dayOfMonth==21||dayOfMonth==31)
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'st'MMM, yyyy");
```

if dayOfMonth like **1,21,31** will use `"dd'st' MMM YYYY"` and so on.

One other way is try this...

```
String str="'th'";
String s="dd"+str+"MMM, yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(str);
```

You can change `str="'st'"` and `str="'rd'"`

One more way come to my mind is By the use of method you just need **ONE** SimpleDate format

```
public String Method(String str)//pass"''th","'st'" or "'nd'"
{
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"+str+"MMM, yyyy");
return formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()).toString();
}
```

**Try this method(ANS for your UPDATED Question):**

```
public boolean CheckForST(String yourdate)

{
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'st' MMM, yyyy");
        formatter2.parseObject(yourdate);

        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        return false;

    }
}
```

Which is only implemented for 'st' you can do the same for 'rd' or 'nd'

Comment: Will you give me one more example, i don't understand this actually what it means.. what `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);` do I don't understand.

Comment: so if i ll do something like second way and then get dayOfMonth and then as per it I ll pass control to If parts then it will work or not ??

Comment: something like `if(dayOfMonth==1||dayOfMonth==21||dayOfMonth==31){
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'st'MMM, yyyy");
        }else if(dayOfMonth==2||dayOfMonth==22){
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'nd'MMM, yyyy");
        }else if(dayOfMonth==3||dayOfMonth==23){
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'rd'MMM, yyyy");
        }else{
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd'th'MMM, yyyy");
        }` and then further processing. now you get it ?